# How to set a timeout for session?

Tags: android

I have a login screen and which sets username as shared preference variable. Now i want to set a time out period for that session variable. Is it is possible to set a timeout period for session in android? Please help me to setup the code.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you exactly want in term of usablity .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just save the time on login as a preference variable? Note that this is not a safe way to implement sessions, but since you dont provide more Information i cant give more detail how to solve *better*